# Windows command line com-port writing for Arduino

Tags: windows, command-line, arduino

I need to send some information from my PC to an Arduino. I tested it with [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) and it works great.

I need to send characters, '1' or '2', to control a servo and I am  using these commands:

> mode com10:9600,n,8,1

... and I see that my Arduino received some data.

After that, I try to use that:

> echo 1>com10

OR

> echo "1">com10

and nothing nothing happens.

With PuTTY it works corrent and turning, when I press 1 or 2. With the Arduino serial monitor it works great too.

Comment: Do you press the Enter key in putty?

Comment: echo 1 >> \\.\COM10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I used [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) to do this task:

```
powershell "$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM10,9600,None,8,one; $port.open(); $port.WriteLine("1"); $port.Close()"
```

Comment: I had tried PHP, C++, Python, and countless modes with no avail. Your solution worked for me under Windows 7. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was, something like:

```
echo ON > \\.\COM4
echo OFF > \\.\COM4
```

[This](https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/simple-trick-for-sending-characters-to-a-serial-port-in-windows/) link provides some good info.

So, in general, the format to send simple ASCII chars to serial port:

```
echo [ASCII chars / string you want to send]    >       \\.\    [Com Port #]
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is very useful when working with Arduinos, here is a [link](http://jfrmilner.wordpress.com/2012/12/30/powershell-power-sockets-arduinorf-part-3-use-powershell-to-send-serial-commands-to-your-arduino/) to a post where I did the same.

I've added a COM port lookup and some error handling to ease the process. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

---

mode com3 BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 STOP=1 && echo blahblah > com3

---

about the same:

---

```
powershell "$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM10,9600,None,8,one; $port.open(); $port.WriteLine("1"); $port.Close()"
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This will send the contents of a file to COM10 under Windows 7, not sure about other versions:

copy myfile \\.\COM10

If you just use "copy myfile COM10" then it creates a file called COM10 instead.

So you might like to try:

echo 1>\\.\com10

Answer (score -1):

Three points:

1. COM10 isn't a reserved file name like COM1–4, so it *could* be that you're just creating a file.
2. `echo 1>foo` is the same as `echo >foo` which will print `ECHO is on.` (you're redirecting stream 1, aka stdout).
3. `echo "1">foo` will print `"1"` *including* the quotes.

To actually echo a `1` somewhere you'd have to use

```
>foo echo 1
```

or

```
(echo 1)>foo
```